# Can I do client side fetching inside the server side render component?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Can I perform client-side data fetching inside a component that's being rendered on a server-side rendered page? I have a page located at `pages/solution/[solutionId]/index.js`, which is server-side rendered, and it contains three components that should be performing client-side fetching. However, I am not getting any data, and it is returning `null`.

index.js

```
const Solution = ({ solution }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
  const { user } = useAuthContext()

  return (
    <>
      <div className="px-5 row-start-2 row-end-3 col-start-2 col-end-3 mb-4">
        // doing client-side fetching
        <ShowWebsite
          url={solution?.liveWebsiteUrl}
          github={solution?.githubUrl}
          title={solution?.title}
          isPlayground={solution?.isPlayground}
        />
        <div className="grid grid-col-1 md:grid-cols-[1fr_160px] items-start gap-x-5 mt-10">
          <SolutionComments /> // doing client side fetching
          <EmojiSection /> // doing client side fetching
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Solution

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const { solutionId } = query
  console.log(solutionId)
  const solution = await getDocument("solutions", solutionId)

  return {
    props: {
      solution,
    },
  }
}
```

SolutionsComment:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

import { useCollection } from "../../hooks/useCollection"

import Comment from "./Comment"
import CommentForm from "./CommentForm"

const SolutionComments = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
  const { documents } = useCollection(`solutions/${id}/comments`)

  return (
    <div className="mt-10 md:mt-0">
      <CommentForm docID={id} />
      <div className="mt-10">
        {documents &&
          documents.map((comment) => (
            <Comment
              key={comment.id}
              comment={comment}
              replies={comment.replies}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

EmojiSection:

```
import React from "react"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

import { useDocument } from "../../hooks/useDocument"

import Emoji from "./Emoji"

const EmojiSection = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id: docID } = router.query
  const { document: reactions } = useDocument(`solutions/${docID}/reactions`, "emojis")
  console.log(reactions)

  return (
    // JSX CODE
  )
}
```

useCollection:

```
import { collection, onSnapshot} from "firebase/firestore"

export const useCollection = (c) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    let ref = collection(db, c)

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      const results = []

      snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (doc) => {
          results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          setError("could not fetch the data")
        }
      )
      // update state
      setDocuments(results)
      setIsLoading(false)
      setError(null)
    })
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [])

  return { documents, error, isLoading }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `SolutionComments`, and `EmojiSection` ? I think that's why someone downvoted you.

Comment: @yousoumar just added code for those components.

Comment: I'm doing client side data fetching inside those components from firebase. My question is Can I do that because currently, I'm getting null when I do `console.log(documents)` in the SolutionComments component?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The problem is elsewhere than the client or server components here. Ensure you get the correct `id`, calling the correct endpoint...